# CKEditor + Plugin Linked Select Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ckeditor

I am writing a CKEditor Plugin, and have got my head around the basics i.e.

```
CKEDITOR.dialog.add( 'addDocumentGroupDialog', function ( editor ) {

    return {
        title: 'Link to a document group',
        minWidth: 400,
        minHeight: 200,
        contents: [
            {
                id: 'tab-groups',
                label: 'Add Document Group Link',
                elements: [
                    {
                        type : "text",
                        id : "documentGroupTitle",
                        label : "Set a link label"
                    },
                    {
                            type : "select",
                            id : "documentGroup",
                            label : "Select a document group from the list to create a link",
                            items : window.documentGroups
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        onOk:function(){
            var dialog = this;

            groupId = dialog.getValueOf("tab-groups", "documentGroup");
            groupTitle = dialog.getValueOf("tab-groups", "documentGroupTitle");
            theDiv = document.createElement("div");
            anchor = document.createElement("a");
            anchor.setAttribute("href", "/documents.php?gid=" + groupId)
            anchor.innerHTML = groupTitle;
            theDiv.appendChild(anchor);
            editor.insertHtml(theDiv.innerHTML);
        }
    };

});
```

However what I would like todo is have one select which then updates a second select. I.e. a cascade. Has anyone seen this done, or got an example of it that they could point me in the direction of?

Thanks for your help

James

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery.change() method? You can get the selected value from the first drop down when it is selected. Use this to determine which values to show in the second drop down.

Comment: I haven't no. My J Query isn't great. Where would that go? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As 97ldave mentioned, `jQuery.change()`

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#selectBox').change(function() {

        var value = $(this).val();

        if (typeof value == 'undefined' || value == '') {
            return; // Don't do anything when the active selection has a value of nothing.
        }

        // If something with a value is selected, do this
        alert(value);

    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the [link dialog definition](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js#L45) for an inspiration. Depending on which type of the link you select, different elements are shown (which is in fact almost exactly what you want).

Define the [onChange](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/plugins/link/dialogs/link.js#L128) handler in the first select element, then using [dialog.getContentElement](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dialog-method-getContentElement) do whatever you want with the second [select element](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.ui.dialog.select).